# Цепочки асинхронных вызовов в ActionScript 3: как передавать параметры насквозь?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ооп, асинхронность, actionscript

В Air приложении есть момент загрузки картинок с внешнего сайта, с записью в файловый кэш, сохранением в памяти его BitmapData и отображения.

Обслуживает это мой класс Кэша. Он получает очередной запрос со ссылкой, и должен отдать BitmapData картинки (запустив кастом событие с данными картинки). Варианта три:

- url новый-незнакомый. Надо скачать файл, сохранить его на диске и отдать BMD;
- url уже как-то давно скачивали, файл есть на диске - надо открыть и отдать BMD;
- url только что уже запрашивали, BMD есть в Dictionary в памяти.

В первом случае получается последовательная цепочка асинхронных вызовов:

1. запрос файла по url с помощью URLLoader;
2. событие: файл докачался. Надо сохранить его данные из `urlLoader.data` в локальный файл. А ещё получить из них Bitmap. Для этого создаём loader, и в него через loadByteArray() загружаем данные файла, чтобы получить их в виде BitmapData.
3. loader догрузил данные. Можно получить BMD.

Через всю эту цепочку нужно передать исходный url. Чтобы в конце записать пару url + BitmapData в словарь кэша-в-памяти и верyть BMD.

Сейчас я на каждом этапе в отдельный словарь пишу пару `DictStep1[loader] = url;` Чтобы по событию окончания, вытащить url из словаря `url = DictStep1[ evnt.target];` и передать в другой словарь с новым загрузчиком, который будет выполнять очередной асинхронный метод.

Может это не самый аккуратный/правильный способ? Как ещё можно "оформить" такие цепочки асинхронных вызовов, чтобы передавать через них сквозной параметр?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более логично использовать класс Loader - он уже содержит и BitmapData и урл картинки.

Еще можно отнаследовать URLLoader и создать в нем поле которое будет хранить ваш урл.

Comment: URLLoader нужен, чтобы получить сырые данные скачанного файла как ByteArray — для сохранения локальной копии в кэш-файл. Так что тут именно цепочка: сначала URLLoader, затем Loader.

Comment: loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytes - тут уже есть эти сырые данные в виде ByteArray

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo

Comment: Спасибо за хинт! Пропустил сей момент. Где-то на форумах нашел пример с сохранением в файл, и не полез перепроверять.
Но всё же, в более общей перспективе, правильно ли так "тащить" сквозь пороги переменную, или стоит как-то иначе поступать?

Comment: Чем меньше наружу из класса "торчит" всяких методов и полей/свойств, тем лучше по ООП парадигме. Работу с кешем тоже лучше закрыть внутри кастомного класса от Loader/URLLoader. Чтобы избегать "таскания" данных по цепочкам вызовов и упорядочивания этих вызовов, я (imho) закидываю эти действия в цепочки задач, примерно так:

Comment: var images:Array = []; // для всяких данных
    var tasks:TasksSequence = new TasksSequence();
    tasks.push( new CashLoadTask());
    tasks.push( new GetURLsTask());
    tasks.push( new LoadImagesTask());
    tasks.push( new DisplayImagesTask());
    tasks.addEventListener("DONE", doneHandler);
    tasks.run();

Comment: Сейчас так и есть: класс Cache, синглтон. Внутри него есть эти несколько словарей. Идею спёр из [этого рецепта Adobe](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Caching_Images_to_disk_after_first_time_they_are_l-10784.html).
Другой вариант, это объектики для каждого отдельного вызова, так поступаю для одноступенчатых вызовов к внешнему API. Есть цепочка, или один асинхроннный вызов — есть такой объект, который хранит нужные сквозные данные, а по завершении в переданный ему в начале коллбэк, отдает что там он получил в итоге. Видимо, так сделаю и для многоходовых асинхронов с картинками.

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от конкретной реализации, но я бы делал все действия в одном классе, где хранил бы связку пару URL/Bitmap.
Второй вариант, сделать обёртки для классов с передачей параметра URL.
И третий, насколько мне не изменяет память у любого класса загрузки по URL, внутри хранится тот самый URL с которого идёт загрузка, к нему можно обратиться.